# Select latest product code

Tags: sql, sybase, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 fields - account_no, date, product.

It is unique by account_no, date.

I want to generate a table containing all account_no, and the latest product - i.e. the product from the latest date with the account_no.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry can't post sample of data. What comes to mind is doing it in two stages. Create a table of account_no, max(date) as date, and inner join this with the original table by account_no and date.

But I don't know if that is the most optimal way of doing it...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But couldn't you just select account_no, product, max(date) from x group by account_no, product?

Comment: This question is very common. I've added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. You should read some of the solutions offered in the past.

Comment: @Andrew, that is not what the OP wants. They want to know *which* product has the latest date per account_no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably look like this

```
    select account_no, product
    from table as T1
    where (T1.account_no, T1.date) in (select account_no, max(date) from 
(select account_no, date from table T2 where T2.account_no = T1.account_no))
```

This is Oracle/postgreSQL syntax but you can get the idea from it.

Hope it helps!